# Unity Android C++ DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, android, c++, unity-game-engine, android-studio-3.0

Who can tell what is wrong with my test project where I am trying to use native C++ code in unity from .so files generated from Android Studio?

Link for unity project: https://github.com/Sv9zIsT/UnityTest/blob/master/C%2B%2BTEST.rar

Link for Android Studio project: https://github.com/Sv9zIsT/UnityTest/blob/master/CTestUnityPackage.rar

I did all recommendations from unity docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidNativePlugins.html

I tried example from unity docs above.

Always result is DllNotFoundException  
and it appears when I call the any function from the .so first time in C# class like:

```
[DllImport("unityTest")]
private static extern int PrintANumber();

void Start()
{
    String str = "";
    str += "PrintANumber() " + PrintANumber() + "\n";
```

...

I have put the plugins into Assets/Plugins/Android/armeabi-v7a/ and Assets/Plugins/Android/x86/ respectively.

Test in several unity's editor versions - it isn't influenced.

What I've done wrong guys?

Comment: Your're testing this in the Unity Editor on a Windows or linux machine?

Comment: Yes I test in Editor on Win 10 machine the error appears in editor and on Android device happens nothing :)

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/testing-so-file-on-windows-unity.312773/

Comment: From my understanding, you cannot test .so objects on windows.  You would need to use a .dll, however for android you would need the .so.